# How to make multiple authentication with resttemplate behind the proxy

Tags: java, spring-boot, proxy, resttemplate

I have spring-boot microservice running behind a proxy. I do authentication for proxy to reach remote system, remote system is also have a basic authentication. hıw can i add proxy authentication and basic authentication together.

```
            HttpHost proxy = null;
            RequestConfig config = null;
            String credentials = proxyUser + ":" + proxyPassword;
            String encodedAuthorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());

            Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.PROXY_AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + encodedAuthorization); 
            List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
            headers.add(header);
```

proxyuser and proxypassword is needed for my proxyserver authentication. remote system needs basic authentication with a token. how to add multiple authentication in resttemplate?

Comment: Just add an authorization header.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i am aading it for my proxyserver already, what about remote api authentication? you mean add 1 more basic header for remote?

Answer (score 1):

After much doing the surfing, I got this answer which perfectly suits my ask

Create the Rest Client Base class so that this can be applicable for all the rest Template calls

public class RestClientBase {
private RestTemplate restTemplate = null;

```
protected RestTemplate getTemplate() {
    string username = "username";
    String Password = "password";

    if (restTemplate == null) {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpReq = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("Proxy URL", PROXY_PORT)); // PROXY PORT needs to be integer
        clientHttpReq.setProxy(proxy);

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpReq);
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(username, Password));
    }

    return restTemplate;
}
```

}

Now Inherit this class in your actual rest client class where you are calling another API endpoint

public class ActualClientClass extends RestClientBase {

```
public String invokeActualService(String restAPINeedingUserNamePwdURL, class.String) {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    String authHeader = null;
    String username = "username";
    String Password = "password";
    HttpEntity < String > entity = null;
    String credentials = username + ":" + Password;
    String encodedAuthorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes());
    authHeader = "Basic" + encodedAuthorization;
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
    entity = new HttpEntity < > (headers);

    String result = getTemplate().exchange(restAPINeedingUserNamePwdURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    
    return result;
}
```

}

Just to highlight, this is exactly doing the same task as curl --proxy-user username:password