# How to add multiple authorization headers in spring boot resttemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following common configuration in my Spring Boot application:

```java
    private RestTemplate getRestTemplate(String username, String pwd){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(username, pwd));
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Right now I am using BasicAuthenticationInterceptor to add basic auth credentials to the Http 'Authorization' headers.

My new requirement asks to add another Http 'Authorization' header with a OAuth/JWT token. So I added something like this below:

```java
headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, escape(token));
```

But as I was using Spring's BasicAuthenticationInterceptor when I add token as "Authorization" header because of the if condition in the spring BasicAuthenticationInterceptor class it is not adding the basic auth credentials. Please find below if condition for more info:

```java
public class BasicAuthenticationInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    private final String encodedCredentials;

    public BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(String username, String password) {
        this(username, password, (Charset)null);
    }

    public BasicAuthenticationInterceptor(String username, String password, @Nullable Charset charset) {
        this.encodedCredentials = HttpHeaders.encodeBasicAuth(username, password, charset);
    }

    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        if (!headers.containsKey("Authorization")) { /* here it will not add if I already have an Authorization header*/
            headers.setBasicAuth(this.encodedCredentials);
        }

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

So I was thinking may be I need to write my own custom Interceptor but before doing so I wanted to see if there is already a existing Interceptor that can fulfill my request. BTW, I was hoping to use BasicAuthorizationInterceptor but is deprecated in 5.3.9(my current spring version).

And in a sidenote, if I am going to write a new interceptor (if that is what you suggest.) then I also wanted to add the token auth header in that custom interceptor.

Any input or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make multiple authentication with resttemplate behind the proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813824/how-to-make-multiple-authentication-with-resttemplate-behind-the-proxy)

Comment: Sorry I am not looking for behind the proxy and the link is using the BasicAuthenticationInterceptor only which I wanted to avoid because of the issue mentioned in the post.